# hide all child of ul except one that has div with specific class jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to hide all children of `ul` except one that has `div` with a specific
class. I want when clicking on an anchor tag with class `h4` hide all `li` elements except any `li` that contains a `div` with class `header4`. My view has a `ul` with a `foreach` loop for `li` inside.

```
<ul id="itemContainer" class="posts">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li class="first">
        <div class="date">
        </div>
        if (condition) {
        <div class="gallery-container arrow header1">
        </div>
        } if (condition) {
        <div class="gallery-container arrow header2">
        </div>
        } if (condition) {
        <div class="gallery-container arrow header3">
        </div>
        } if (condition) {
        <div class="gallery-container arrow header4">
        </div>
        }
    </li>
    }
</ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="h4">click</a></li>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.h4').click(function() {

            alert("1");
            $("#itemContainer").children().hide();
            $('.header4').show();
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Start by spelling children correctly. Also when you have jQuery issues, post only HTML and JavaScript in a [mcve] - click the `<>` to edit a snippet. You will see the syntax highlighter will excpect a `})})` at the end too

Comment: You also have syntax error

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#itemContainer').children(':not(.header4)').hide();
```

or

```
$('#itemContainer .header4').siblings().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

your main mistake is typo in `children()` method. also I suggest using jQuery `.not()` instead of hiding all and showing 'header4' - with this approach you will avoid flickering

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.h4').click(function() {

    alert("1");
    $("#itemContainer").children().not('.header4').hide();

  });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  }

li {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

a{
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #AAA;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Verdana;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="itemContainer">
  <li class="header1">1</li>
  <li class="header2">2</li>
  <li class="header3">3</li>
  <li class="header4">4</li>
  
</ul>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="h4">click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have many syntax issues in you code.
You can find all `children` `li`s within the `ul` and `hide` all `div` but `header4` as follows,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.h4').click(function() {


    $("#itemContainer").children().each(function() {
      $(this).find('div:not(.header4)').hide();
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="itemContainer" class="posts">
  <li class="first">
    <div class="date">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-container arrow header1">header1
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-container arrow header2">header2
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-container arrow header3">header3
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-container arrow header4">header4
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="second">
    <div class="date">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-container arrow header1">header1
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-container arrow header2">header2
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-container arrow header3">header3
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-container arrow header4">header4
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="h4">click</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery like below

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="itemContainer" class="posts">
    <li class="first">
        <div class="date">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-container arrow header1">header1
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-container arrow header2">header2
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-container arrow header3">header3
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-container arrow header4">header4
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="h4">click</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.h4').click(function () {
            $("#itemContainer li .arrow").hide();
            $("#itemContainer li .arrow.header4").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is ineffective usage of css selectors with jQuery